# Bootstrap: ScrollSpy and smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two problems with Bootstrap: I can't add `ScrollSpy` and smooth scroll at my Boostrap site.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#test">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div id="test" class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-  target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">L</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
 <div id="test" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class=""><a href="#Chi Sono">Chi Sono</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#Conoscenze">Conoscenze</a></li>
  <li><a href="#OS" >Sistemi operativo</a></li>


 </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>
```

This is the navbar code. I've tried many solutions, but to no avail. How do I add this effect?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
      <div id=test ...>
```

with

```
       <nav id=test...>
```

add the data-target attribute with the ID or class of the parent element of any Bootstrap .nav component. Since you are using div when defining id of data-target for scrollspy, it won't work. use nav instead
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

And another error in this part  of your code here

```
   </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

do the navbar-collapse with nav tag not the div tag.

so the correct code is

```
   </nav><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: there is one more syntax error in your code. The end tag is nav , not div. So change the ending tag in the last but one line.

Comment: if my answer is correct, click the correct answer button. Thank you.

Comment: did you try the last error which i pointed out? did you add the bootstrap.js file as well to your application, because it works because of a javascript class. so you have to add it to the appropriate directory.